# Installed Python and Idle is not available

Tags: python, installation, python-idle, failed-installation

On my desktop PC. I downloaded and installed Python and was able to get the IDLE program. But on my laptop, I am getting nothing. *See Image Below*. Why isn't Python IDLE application not available? But when I type in "python" I am only getting the Python black command prompt box. *Like this in the screenshot below.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling it with the advanced options to make sure you are setting its PATH and getting the IDLE too. If that doesn't work, reply to my comment and we'll try to work it out.

Comment: This question is a bit off topic because it is not directly about programming.  But anyway, when you install with the python.org installer, which it looks like you did, tkinter and IDLE are a combined option with a checkbox.  Try `import idlelib.idle` at the python `>>>` prompt.  Or look in .../Python3.7/Lib/ for idlelib.